# Get EIP as output from aws-cdk generated VPC definition

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

There is a vpc definition via

```
 const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'SomeVPC', {
        cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
        maxAzs: 2,
 });
```

Under the hood it creates 2 EIP for NAT gateways

```
"SomeVPCPublicSubnet1EIP58E3D6C5": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
  "Properties": {
    "Domain": "vpc"
  }
}
```

how to grab the references to them and export it via `CfnOutput`? Something like this:

```
new CfnOutput(this, "ExternalIPOutput", {value: <some magic call to get SomeVPCPublicSubnet1EIP58E3D6C5.ref()>})
```

Comment: What would you like to pick? `CfnOutput` print strings only

Comment: @AmitBaranes just need the IP itself to import then it in a separate stack into security grp

Comment: I recommend working with ssm then, it would be easier to write to ssm and read from it.
What do you mean by the IP itself? please provide more information

Comment: @AmitBaranes did you use aws-cdk? You can define vpc there, under the hood it creates a bunch of different components. One of them - EIP. I need somehow grab the reference to it via cdk api. That's my question. As a result I want stack output where IP is printed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while but I faced this issue today and this is how I managed to handle it and grab the EIP -

**Code Snippet:**

```js
// Create new VPC
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC', {
    cidr: props.customCidr,
    maxAzs: 2,
    subnetConfiguration: [
        {
            name: 'Private',
            subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE
        },
        {
            name: 'Public',
            subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
        }
    ]
});

// Get Elastic IP 
vpc.publicSubnets.forEach((subnet, index) => {
  // Find the Elastic IP
  const EIP = subnet.node.tryFindChild('EIP') as ec2.CfnEIP
  new cdk.CfnOutput(this, `output-eip-${index}`, { value: EIP.ref });
})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad i could help :)